# why my project can only send out 2 email at 1 time?

Tags: php, email

i am trying to send out 20 email at 1 time but when i run my php file and it only send out 2 out of 20 email. i keep try to reload my php page and its only will send out 2 at a time. so, what can i do for my code below?

```
<?
require_once "lib/base.inc.php";

$arrResult = $oAdminEmail->getQueEmail();

for($i=0; $i<count($arrResult); $i++)
{
    $iId = $arrResult[$i]['id'];
    $email = $arrResult[$i]['contact_email'];
    $name = $arrResult[$i]['contact_first']." ".$arrResult[$i]['contact_last'];
    $message = "test"; 
    $subject = "test";
    $sendFlag = $eMailer->sendEDM($email,$name,$subject,$message);

    if ($sendFlag) 
            {
                $update['status'] = 1;
                $update_edm = $oAdminEmail->updateEmailStatus($update,$iId);
            }
}


?>

function getQueEmail()
        {
            global $db;
            $arrResult = array();

            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM "._CONST_TBL_EMAIL_OUTGOING." WHERE status = '0' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20";

            if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
            {
                $arrResult = $rs->GetArray();           
            }

            return $arrResult;
        }
```

Comment: How can you ensure it sends only two?

Comment: i created 20 dummy data its only store my email address. after i run my page and i only receive 2 email.

Comment: Are you sure that in for loop it is iterating 20 times?

Comment: yap. when i hide "$sendflag" and ehco $email i will get 20 email address from my database.

Comment: Ok, it may be due to long execution time. When you refresh page, email sending operation may takes long and php stops working. See this setting `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`. Also, open your error log to see if there is any error. Have you got any error on page? Your error show may be closed

Comment: i found it the error is come from my server. and now i have solve it. thx for help bro.

Comment: Ok, you can provide your answer after one day as an answer to your question for incomng users